# OS X Terminal Remote Connection Port Number

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, connection

I've been trying to set up a remote connection via terminal, but I'm running into a few issues.

This is how I initially had it set up:

```
ssh root@***.***.***.**
```

Then I tried to add the -p 1234, but it the port number kept getting removed when closing the remove connection window. So then I referred to this tutorial:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/03/create-ssh-bookmarks-in-terminal-for-mac-os-x/

But that still didn't work. Any ideas how I can add the port number just once without having to re-enter it upon connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the problem. Imagine the format of the SSH command line string as follows:

```
ssh [user@]server
```

Now, to make sure that your custom port is always part of that, we *don't* add a username, and use `-p 1234 root@hostname_or_ip` as the *hostname*, resulting in

```
ssh -p 1234 root@hostname_or_ip
```

This will be the `ssh` command line used whenever you select this entry from the servers list.

The following works like a charm connecting to a system with SSH port 220 and IP address 172.16.215.150 as root:

[image: Screenshot]